# Python - timeseries Normalize/Scaling to base 100

Tags: python, pandas

I have this `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {'2020-01': 50, '2020-02': 70, '2020-03': 30},
 'B': {'2020-01': 10, '2020-02': 14, '2020-03': 9},
 'C': {'2020-01': 200, '2020-02': 100, '2020-03': 300}})
```

`df`:

[image]

And I'm looking for this output:

[image]

How? Well, as you can see it's timeseries data, and as I want to plot the evolution and the differences in time between the variables `A`, `B`, `C` I need to scale them to base 100. So, each variable will start with `100` and the next value shows the increase/decrease of the last value based on the first value (100).

For example, `A` starts at 50 (100), then changes to 70 (+40% based on first month = 140), then changes to 30 (-80% based on first month = 60), and so on. I think there should be some package or function that does this (as it's very used for stock market visualizations), but I can't find none.  Any suggestions?

PS: You can assume the data has just 3 variables, but there is thousands of rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df = 100*(df / df.iloc[0, :])

df

            A      B      C
2020-01  100.0  100.0  100.0
2020-02  140.0  140.0   50.0
2020-03   60.0   90.0  150.0
```

Comment: What means IIUC ?

Answer (score 1):

Just write a simple function which takes a Series/list and does the transformation.

```
def trans_100(a):
    a_trans = a[:]
    a_trans[0] = 100
    for i in range(1,len(a)):
        a_trans[i] = 100 + ((a[i] - a[0])*100/a[0])

    return a_trans

print(trans_100([50, 70, 30]))
```

`[100, 140.0, 60.0]`